# Is it possible to fill an inner collection from two different tables?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

In SQL I have two tables `T_PRIO_SAMPLES` and `T_OTHER_SAMPLES`.

In Java I have 4 classes:

**Sample.class**

```
   public abstract class Sample 
   {
      ...
   }
```

**PrioSample.class**

```
   public class PrioSample extends Sample {
      ...
   }
```

**OtherSample.class**

```
   public class OtherSample extends Sample
   {
      ...
   }
```

**Packet.class**

```
   public class Packet 
   {

        List<Sample> samples;

        ...
   }
```

Currently I have two DAO's `PrioSampleDAO` and `OtherSampleDAO`.

**My Question**:

Is it possible to build a `PacketDAO` that on MyBatis level creates Packets and fills the sample list of those with entries from two different tables

or do I have to do this manually on Java level?

**EDIT:**
I want to have a `Packet` object created via the `PacketDAO` and then be able to do something like this:

```
for( Sample sample : packet.getSamples() ) {
    if ( sample instanceof PrioSample ) {
       ...
    }
    else if ( sample instanceof OtherSample) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Hope this claryfies my question a bit.

Comment: What are you using as your framework to retrieve the data?

Comment: Spring 4.1.0 and MyBatis 3.7.8

Answer (score 0):

Define a view that contains the records of both tables.

Comment: Still not able to test it, will do in the next few days.

Comment: The problem is that I have to declare a result map in my query which can only contain one type(?). If I make this type `Sample.class` it would be possible to have samples from both tables in the `Packet` but wouldn't I lose all extra informations that compose the PrioSample and OtherSample?

Comment: Define a new type that contains all information for both classes.

Comment: That'll work, but I think that'd be bad programming because then I've alot redundant logic and 3 classes representing 2 logical objects. Thanks for the effort though.